# Виден ли поcледний элемент списка listview

Tags: android, listview

У меня есть `listview`, мне нужно определить виден ли сейчас на экране последний элемент списка.

```
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewMatches);
lv.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int i) {
        if(i == 0){
            //тут нужно определить, виден ли последний элемент списка
            Log.d("ggloor_msg", "onScrollStateChanged: --------");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int i, int i1, int i2) {  
    }
});
```

Comment: Не знаю есть ли это в листвью, который морально устарел, но вот в RecyclerView.LayoutManager есть метод findLastVisiblePosition(), который возвращает позицию последнего отрисованого холдера

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать этот метод:

```
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int i, int i1, int i2) {  
    if (((i + i1) == i2) && (i2 > 0)) {
        //список прокручен до конца
        // первое условие проверяет прокручен ли список до конца вниз (i - первый видимый элемент, i1 - количество видимых, i2 - всего элементов)
        //второе условие проверяет пуст ли список, чтобы обработчик не срабатывал каждое мгновение на пустом списке
    }
}
```